# git fork from certain tag version - requirements.txt

Tags: django, git, github

I want to fork one github project code, but not from master branch, but from older release.

Reason: I want to edit one place in the code in my fork version and put the url of this tag version into my requirements.txt so that

```
pip install -e git+https://git_url_to_my_form_in_this_tag_version
```

works.

I found the tag version in github, but once I fork it, it is being forked from master and not from exactly that tag.

how can I do it?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/13685920/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe but I want to fork it so that I can be sure that my change is forever there. I need to change the code first after fork, and then install via pip

Comment: Wait, which part of this are you stuck on? Specifying your forked, modified version in the `requirements.txt` or forking from the right version in the first place? If the latter, how about http://stackoverflow.com/q/9227873/3001761?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Forking the repository clones the **entire** repository, not just the master branch. You can then checkout the tag you want to work on, make the required changes, and create a new tag.

```
# checkout the tag
git checkout tag_to_fork_from

# alternatively, create a new branch starting with the tag
git checkout -b mybranch tag_to_fork_on
```

Comment: thanks, I just cloned the code and changed the code and put aside for later installability via pip

Comment: the new branch is now: https://github.com/bevedoni/django-allauth/tree/nametests_adjusted_version  

this version can be installed via: 

``pip install -e git+https://github.com/bevedoni/django-allauth/tree/nametests_adjusted_version``   right?

Comment: Instead of asking whether it will work, why not try it instead ;)

Comment: Using the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13685920/3001761) that @jonrsharpe gave you, I think you want `pip install git+git://github.com/bevedoni/django-allauth.git@nametests_adjusted_version`